# dynamic html into a view using ui router

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular5

Ok so i am not looking for an example more of help with an approach i am primarily a java developer so please excuse (and correct) the terminology if it need be. This is also why i need help as i am still early on into my journey into angular.

So i am using angular 5, along with ui-router. I am trying to design a three tabbed page [view, html, css] where the html and css will be text areas where a user will enter said thing, then , the view will be the rendering of that. There will be data (can be fetched prior to or at the time of rendering the view) that will bind to that html. The user will basically be putting in angular templates.

I have been reading [this example](https://eyalvardi.wordpress.com/2016/09/04/injecting-components-in-runtime/) but not sure if that is the proper approach.

Comment: what i am going to attempt to do is create a component and then register it, then create a state with said component and register that and try to transition to it. I will post it as the answer if it works..... if ....

Answer (score 0):

this article had the solution 
https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e

basically it looks like this

```
@ViewChild("ancc", { read: ViewContainerRef }) container;

@Input() property:Property = new Property();

constructor(private  resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,private _compiler: Compiler){
    console.log("hit layout constructor");
}
view(){

    // create the template
    const template = '<span>generated on the fly: {{property.label}}</span>';
    //clear out the old instance
    this.container.clear();

    const tmpCmp = Component({template: template})(class {
    });
    const tmpModule = NgModule({declarations: [tmpCmp]})(class {
    });

    this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
        .then((factories) => {
            const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
            //attach the component to the view
            const cmpRef = this.container.createComponent(f);
            //bind the data
            cmpRef.instance.property = this.property;
        })
}
```

hope this helps someone!